# What exactly is the onclick of a DOM object in JS?

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

What exactly is the onclick of a DOM object in JS? I've seen it being called as the onclick property, but isn't it a method? I tried calling .onclick() after assigning a function to it and it worked just like a method with no click.

Comment: It's a property you set to a function that gets called when the element is clicked

Comment: U mean the method called itself without any click event ?

Comment: It's a property.. `__lookupGetter__("onclick")` does not return null.  IOW: it has a getter / setter.

Comment: @VigneshRaja yes, after assigning a function to it I called it on the next line and the function was invoked. Not much useful but good for understanding its behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods are properties with a function as the value. So the onclick property is a method because its value is a function. Try using element.onclick() Before you assign a function to it.

It will throw an error since null values can't be called. If onclick was like a method on its prototype chain that you overwrite, you'd be able to call it before 'overwriting' with element.onclick = function(){};

So any clean element without an onclick handler will have null as the value of its onclick property. Same for all other standard event handler properties.